# Java Regular Expression for ICD Codes doesn´t work

Tags: java, regex

I have written the following Java code:

```
public void test(final String myString){
   final String rule = "^[A-Z]\\d{2}(\\.\\d){0,2}$";
   final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rule);
   final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);

   if(!matcher.matches()){
         System.out.println("Failure, the String" + myString + " is not valid!");
   }
}
```

The Regular Expression should by valid the following String:

```
[character are required][number are required][number are required][point is optional][number is optional][number is optional]
```

It is important, that if a point was declared in the string, at least one Number must be followed!

My solution only works for Strings like J45 or J45.9

Java Java like these are allowed:

```
D99
M00.0
M01.6
J98.3
T05.0
M96.81
D68.20
```

Java Strings like these are not allowed:

```
9D.0
6G
7H.
M96.811
J234.82
G687.1
GU87.11
```

How I can solve this problem by using Regular Expressions in Java?

Comment: I think you did not provide all testing cases, or your *[point is optional][number is optional][number is optional]* rule is not correct, hence, see two options in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> [point is optional][number is optional][number is optional]

You need to make the dot optional and set the `{0,2}` quantifier to the `\d` pattern only:

```
^[A-Z]\d{2}\.?\d{0,2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q7LZo3/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `[A-Z]`  - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `\d{2}` - any 2 digits
- `\.?` - *an optional* dot
- `\d{0,2}` - any 0 to 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Since you are using `.matches()` that anchors the pattern by default, you may declare it without the `^` and `$` anchors as

```
final String rule = "[A-Z]\\d{2}\\.?\\d{0,2}";
```

See an [online Java test](http://ideone.com/ILvfTQ).

Or, if there must be 1 or 2 digits after a dot, or if no dot is present 0 to 2 digits are allowed, you may consider using

```
^[A-Z]\d{2}(?:\.\d{1,2}|\d{0,2})$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q7LZo3/2), and use as

```
final String rule = "[A-Z]\\d{2}(?:\\.\\d{1,2}|\\d{0,2})";
```

where `(?:\\.\\d{1,2}|\\d{0,2})` matches either a `.` and then any 1 or 2 digits, OR any 0 to 2 digits.

Comment: Could you explain, why you have defined the character ':' in your last expression? Thenaks !

Comment: @Marwief See [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471). Just grouped two alternatives without capturing the submatches, i.e. without storing those texts in memory.

Comment: @Marwief Look, Anthony interpreted your `[point is optional][number is optional][number is optional]` as `optional( [point is required][number is required][number is required] )`. What are your real requirements?

Answer (score 0):

This regex expression:

- Requires one Uppercase Letter followed by 2 number digits
- Followed by an optional combination of a point and 1-2 number digits

  ```
  ^[A-Z]\d{2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
  ```